Are these price stickers or price labels or both in American English?
Are these price stickers or price labels in American English?



Why do you have six icons for 5 dollars there? What do you mean AmE? The dollar sign goes next to the number like this: $5.00. That is a price sticker not a price label (clothes). Marshalls is an AmE apparel stores that also sells, among other things, kitchenware. soaps and perfumes and some memorabilia. The stores are also in Canada. Canada has Canadian dollars but they don't put/show CAN that on labels. It looks like your Keep Calm and Carry On poster is damaged.

Sometimes such a label is called a

price tag
a tag on merchandise showing the price at which it is offered for sale

From Merriam-Webster.
Some are tied on, others are stuck.
A Google image search will bring up many examples.

Thank you very much

We often say that had a high price tag even if it is a sticker. Your definition refers to the actual way something is priced physically but that is not the whole story...tied on/stuck on.

@Lambie the answer says "Some are tied on, others are stuck" and that's what the images show. Tied or stuck. Jeez, to borrow your own expletive.

Yes, I was was trying to be subtle. Some are tied on and others are  stuck on.

I could equally well have written "Some are stuck on, others are tied." There is no need to repeat the preposition.
